# Laravel JWT refresh token middleware and simultaneous requests

Tags: php, laravel-5, jwt, laravel-middleware

i have a question about the jwt refresh token middleware and the refresh_ttl config value;

I have a laravel app with JWT. I use the refresh_token middleware to send a new token on every request (and blacklist the previous one), but i'm having a problem with simultaneous requests which invalidates the token of the first request that gets to the server and throw an exception for the second request.

As i understand, the refresh_ttl is the time in which the token will still be available after blacklisted, for scenearios like mine, but is not working for me.

Am i wrong? What's the correct way to make simultaneous requests using the jwt refresh token middleware?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem.

Just in case somebody is having problem with this too, i was setting the TTL and Refresh TTL values, but what i had to set was "blacklist_grace_period", in the JWT config or in the .env file.

Hope this helps somebody

Comment: Okay, so your answer help me to get this to work, but you actually didn't specify the exact env variable you have to use (or maybe it was changed since then). So the key should be "JWT_BLACKLIST_GRACE_PERIOD", and the value should be your desire grace period in minutes(!).

Comment: thanks for sharing @TamasKoos I dont really remember because it was a long time but it feels to me that the exact env variable was changed because i think i'd just specify the correct name.